# Memory usage of WinCE Application

Tags: c++, windows-ce

Is it possible to determine the memory usage of a WIN CE application? The Wince device does not support ActiveSync

Comment: if you can't talk to the device, it's pretty much print statements!

Comment: Why can't you use ActiveSync? What version of CE?

Comment: Also, your accept is quite low.

Comment: @Mitch Wheat: The device provider told us that, they don't support ActiveSync in the device.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Debugging on CE5.0 device without Activesync](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsdteam/archive/2005/04/28/413304.aspx)

[Debugging CE Apps without ActiveSync](http://blog.opennetcf.com/ctacke/PermaLink,guid,136fadf9-a35f-4c10-99b6-0569dc283d19.aspx)

Round up of Power Toys for .NET Compact Framework 3.5: [Spelunking in the .NET Compact Framework](http://mitch-wheat.blogspot.com/2008/03/spelunking-in-net-compact-framework.html)

Answer (score 1):

If your device has some kind of network connectivity, and if you don't mind expending a few dollars on a software tool, you could try using [Soti Pocket Controller](http://www.soti.net/PCPro/). I have been using it for years as a good aid on Windows ce/mobile development.

You could also try some of the [task](http://www.remotetaskmonitor.com/) [managers](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/windows/TaskManager.aspx) available on the web.